# Python multiprocessing.Pool(): am I limited in what I can return?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am using Python's multi-processing pool. I have been told, although not experienced this myself so I cannot post the code, that one cannot just "return" anything from within the `multiprocessing.Pool()`-worker back to the `multiprocessing.Pool()`'s main process. Words like "pickling" and "lock" were being thrown around but I am not sure.

Is this correct, and if so, what are these limitations?

In my case, I have a function which generates a mutable class object and then returns it after it has done some work with it. I'd like to have 8 processes run this function, generate their own classes, and return each of them after they're done. Full code is NOT written yet, so I cannot post it.

Any issues I may run into?

My code is: `res = pool.map(foo, list_of_parameters)`

Comment: is pool multiprocessing.pool, because there are different pools around.

Comment: If it is multiprocessing.pool, you can work with pickable objects, see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Comment: As long as each of the functions returns a **different** mutable object, you're fine.  Multiprocessing requires that the objects be picklable, but the actual pickling is done behind your back.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"Is this correct, and if so, what are these limitations?"*

It depends. It is correct, but the SER/DES processing is the problem here, as a pair of disjoint processes tries to "send" something ( **there:** <sub>a task specification with parameters</sub> **and back:** <sub>... Yessss, the so long waited for result</sub>* )

Initial versions of the Python standard library of modules piece, responsible for doing this, the `pickle`-module, was not able to SER-ialise some more complex types of objects, Class-instances being one such example.

There are newer and newer versions evolving, sure, yet this SER/DES step is one of the SPoFs that may avoid a smooth code-execution for some such cases.

Next are the cases, that finish by throwing a *`Memory Error`* as they request as much memory allocations, that the O/S simply rejects any new request for such an allocation, and the whole process attempt to produce and send `pickle.dumps( ... )` un-resolvably crashes.

---

### Do we have any remedies available?

Well, maybe yes, maybe no - Mike McKearn's `dill` may help in some cases to better handle complex objects in SER/DES-processing.

May try to use `import dill as pickle; pickle.dumps(...)` and test your hot-candidates for `Class()`-instances to get SER/DES-ed, if they get a chance to pass through. If not, no way using this low-hanging fruit first trick.

Next, a less easy way would be to avoid your dependence on hardwired `multiprocessing.Pool()`-instantiations and their (above)-limited SER/comms/DES-methods, and design your processing strategy as a **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** system, based on a communicating agents paradigm.

That way you benefit from a right-sized, just-enough designed communication interchange between intelligent-enough agents, that know (as you've designed them to know it) what to tell one to the others, even without sending any mastodon-sized BLOB(s), that accidentally crash the processing in any of the SPoF(s) you cannot both prevent and salvage ex-post.

There seem no better ways forward I know about or can foresee in 2020-Q4 for doing this safe and smart.